# How to detect text (string) language in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nslinguistictagger

For instance, given the following strings:

```
let textEN = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
let textES = "El zorro marrón rápido salta sobre el perro perezoso"
let textAR = "الثعلب البني السريع يقفز فوق الكلب الكسول"
let textDE = "Der schnelle braune Fuchs springt über den faulen Hund"
```

I want to detect the used language in each of them.

Let's assume the signature for the implemented function is:

```
func detectedLanguage<T: StringProtocol>(_ forString: T) -> String?
```

<sub>returns an *Optional* string in case of no detected language.</sub>

thus the appropriate result would be:

```
let englishDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textEN) // => English
let spanishDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textES) // => Spanish
let arabicDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textAR) // => Arabic
let germanDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textDE) // => German
```

Is there an easy approach to achieve it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Latest versions (iOS 12+)

#### Briefly:

You could achieve it by using [*NLLanguageRecognizer*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nllanguagerecognizer), as:

```
import NaturalLanguage

func detectedLanguage(for string: String) -> String? {
    let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
    recognizer.processString(string)
    guard let languageCode = recognizer.dominantLanguage?.rawValue else { return nil }
    let detectedLanguage = Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: languageCode)
    return detectedLanguage
}
```

---

## Older versions (iOS 11+)

#### Briefly:

You could achieve it by using [*NSLinguisticTagger*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger), as:

```
func detectedLanguage<T: StringProtocol>(for string: T) -> String? {
    let recognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
    recognizer.processString(String(string))
    guard let languageCode = recognizer.dominantLanguage?.rawValue else { return nil }
    let detectedLanguage = Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: languageCode)
    return detectedLanguage
}
```

---

#### Details:

First of all, you should be aware of what are you asking about is mainly relates to the world of *[Natural language processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)*.

<sub>Since NLP is more than text language detection, the rest of the answer will not contains specific NLP information.</sub>

Obviously, implementing such a functionality is not that easy, especially when starting to care about the details of the process such as splitting into sentences and even into words, after that recognising names and punctuations etc... I bet you would think of "what a painful process! it is not even logical to do it by myself"; Fortunately, iOS *does* supports NLP (actually, NLP APIs are available for all Apple platforms, not only the iOS) to make what are you aiming for to be easy to be implemented. The core component that you would work with is [***`NSLinguisticTagger`***](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger):

> Analyze natural language text to tag part of speech and lexical class,
>   identify names, perform lemmatization, and determine the language and
>   script.
>
> `NSLinguisticTagger` provides a uniform interface to a variety of
>   natural language processing functionality with support for many
>   different languages and scripts. You can use this class to segment
>   natural language text into paragraphs, sentences, or words, and tag
>   information about those segments, such as part of speech, lexical
>   class, lemma, script, and language.

As mentioned in the class documentation, the method that you are looking for - under *Determining the Dominant Language and Orthography* section- is [`dominantLanguage(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslinguistictagger/2875117-dominantlanguage):

> Returns the dominant language for the specified string.
>
> .
>
> .
>
> **Return Value**
>
> The [BCP-47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47) tag identifying the dominant language of the string, or the
>   tag "und" if a specific language cannot be determined.

You might notice that the `NSLinguisticTagger` is exist since back to iOS 5. However, `dominantLanguage(for:)` method is *only* supported for iOS 11 and above, that's because it has been developed on top of the [*Core ML Framework*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml):

> . . .
>
> Core ML is the foundation for domain-specific frameworks and
>   functionality. Core ML supports Vision for image analysis, **Foundation**
>   **for natural language processing (for example, the `NSLinguisticTagger`**
>   **class)**, and GameplayKit for evaluating learned decision trees. Core ML
>   itself builds on top of low-level primitives like Accelerate and BNNS,
>   as well as Metal Performance Shaders.
>
> [image]

Based on the returned value from calling `dominantLanguage(for:)` by passing "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog":

```
NSLinguisticTagger.dominantLanguage(for: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

would be "en" optional string. However, so far that is not the desired output, the expectation is to get "English" instead! Well, that is exactly what you should get by calling the [`localizedString(forLanguageCode:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1643226-localizedstring) method from [Locale](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale) Structure and passing the gotten language code:

```
Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: "en") // English
```

#### Putting all together:

As mentioned in the "Quick Answer" code snippet, the function would be:

```
func detectedLanguage<T: StringProtocol>(_ forString: T) -> String? {
    guard let languageCode = NSLinguisticTagger.dominantLanguage(for: String(forString)) else {
        return nil
    }

    let detectedLanguage = Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: languageCode)

    return detectedLanguage
}
```

**Output:**

It would be as expected:

```
let englishDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textEN) // => English
let spanishDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textES) // => Spanish
let arabicDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textAR) // => Arabic
let germanDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textDE) // => German
```

**Note That:**

There still cases for not getting a language name for a given string, like:

```
let textUND = "SdsOE"
let undefinedDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(textUND) // => Unknown language
```

Or it could be even `nil`:

```
let rubbish = "000747322"
let rubbishDetectedLanguage = detectedLanguage(rubbish) // => nil
```

Still find it a not bad result for providing a useful output...

#### Furthermore:

**About NSLinguisticTagger:**

Although I will not going to dive deep in `NSLinguisticTagger` usage, I would like to note that there are couple of really cool features exist in it more than just simply detecting the language for a given a text; As a pretty simple **example**: using the *lemma* when enumerating tags would be so helpful when working with [Information retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval), since you would be able to recognize the word "driving" passing "drive" word.

#### Official Resources

**Apple Video Sessions**:

- For more about Natural Language Processing and how `NSLinguisticTagger` works: [Natural Language Processing and your Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/208/?time=53).

Also, for getting familiar with the CoreML:

- [Introducing Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/703).
- [Core ML in depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/710).

Comment: I don't suppose you found a version that would work on the server?

Comment: @Burf2000 No. You should try to find an approach to work NLP that relates to what the used programming language/framework(s) for your server.

Comment: Sorry, I should of clarified that I mean Swift Server running on Linux as I believe this framework has not been open sourced yet

Comment: @AhmadF In one word! it's unable to detect text (string) language as  result  it's not working for me. would you test this please. `detectLanguage(for: "Islam")`

Comment: @NazmulHasan I will update my answer by adding another different approach. However, keep in mind that `Islam` will be recognized as "Turkish".

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSLinguisticTagger's tagAt method. It support iOS 5 and later.

```
func detectLanguage<T: StringProtocol>(for text: T) -> String? {
    let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger.init(tagSchemes: [.language], options: 0)
    tagger.string = String(text)

    guard let languageCode = tagger.tag(at: 0, scheme: .language, tokenRange: nil, sentenceRange: nil) else { return nil }
    return Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: languageCode)
}

detectLanguage(for: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")              // English
detectLanguage(for: "El zorro marrón rápido salta sobre el perro perezoso")     // Spanish
detectLanguage(for: "الثعلب البني السريع يقفز فوق الكلب الكسول")                // Arabic
detectLanguage(for: "Der schnelle braune Fuchs springt über den faulen Hund")   // German
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried `NSLinguisticTagger` with short input text like `hello`, it always recognizes as Italian.
Luckily, Apple recently added [NLLanguageRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/naturallanguage/nllanguagerecognizer) available on iOS 12, and seems like it more accurate :D

```
import NaturalLanguage

if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
    let languageRecognizer = NLLanguageRecognizer()
    languageRecognizer.processString(text)
    let code = languageRecognizer.dominantLanguage!.rawValue
    let language = Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: code)
}
```